# How to mock a Retrofit Response

Tags: android, kotlin, mocking, retrofit

I'm trying to mock a Retrofit Response when it isn't successful.

```
interface ServiceInterface {
@POST("auth/login")
suspend fun loginRequest(@Body loginInformation: LoginInformation) : Response<LoginResponse>}
```

I made an onSuccess test and it worked, but I don't know how to mock a Response when it isn't successful

```
@Test
fun onCallSuccess() = runBlocking {
    val response = Response.success(LoginResponse(status = "OK", token = "TOKEN"))
    coEvery {
        serviceMock.loginRequest(any())
    } returns response

    loginRepository.doLogin("", "")

    coVerify {
        serviceMock.loginRequest(any())
    }

    assertEquals(LoginResponse(status = "OK", token = "TOKEN"), loginRepository.doLogin("",""))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the retrofit [documentation](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Response.html):

```
public static <T> Response<T> error(int code, okhttp3.ResponseBody body)
```

> Create a synthetic error response with an HTTP status code of code and
> body as the error body.

You should be able to make another test using `Response.error` similar to how you did with `Response.success`

Comment: I tried to use this Response.error, but I don't know what to insert on the second parameter (okhttp3.ResponseBody body), I tried to insert LoginResponse(status = "NOK") but it didn't worked

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33153100/how-to-create-a-retrofit-response-object-during-unit-testing-with-retrofit-2